# Translating ML code to C++

Tags: c++, sml, code-translation

I have found a parsing algorithm [here](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/pubs/unparse-abstract.html), however it is in ML and I'm not too familiar with it. For better understanding of the algorithm I am trying to translate it to an imperative language like C++. Now thee are a few things I'm not sure of or don't really understand.

Here is a header for parsing a postfix expression (AFAIK this is technically not a header, but a match but I am not familiar with functional terms):

```
parse_postfix(stack, (e, []), 
                    ipts as RATOR (irator as (_, _, POSTFIX)) :: ipts') =
```

This means that `ipts` is the head of the list `ipts'` and is a postfix operator? Why is there another match inside (`irator as...`)? Does it remove it from the list or advances anyway? Or is `ipts` the remainder of the list when the operator `irator` is removed?

I'm having a hard time translating this. Here's what I've coded so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum Assoc { Left, Right, Noassoc };
enum Fixity { Prefix, Infix, Postfix };

struct Oper {
    std::string Symbol;
    int Precedence;
    Fixity Fix;     // We can't represent bound types that way (INFIX <assoc>)
    Assoc Asc;      // so we just make it have the operator anyway

    Oper(std::string const& s, int p, Fixity f, Assoc a)
        : Symbol(s), Precedence(p), Fix(f), Asc(a) { }
};

// A regular AST representation
struct Expr { };
struct ConstExpr : public Expr {
    int Value;

    ConstExpr(int i) : Value(i) { }
};
struct UryExpr : public Expr {
    const Expr *Sub;
    Oper *OP;

    UryExpr(const Expr *s, Oper *o)
        : Sub(s), OP(o) { }
};
struct BinExpr : public Expr {
    const Expr *LHS, *RHS;
    Oper *OP;

    BinExpr(const Expr *l, const Expr *r, Oper *o)
        : LHS(l), RHS(r), OP(o) { }
};

bool noparens(Oper *inner, Oper *outer, Assoc side) {
    int pi = inner->Precedence, po = outer->Precedence;
    Fixity fi = inner->Fix, fo = outer->Fix;
    Assoc ai = inner->Asc, ao = outer->Asc;
    if (pi > po) return true;
    if (side == Left && fi == Postfix) return true;
    if (side == Left && fi == Infix && ai == Left) return (fo == Infix && ao == Left);
    if (side == Right && fi == Postfix) return true;
    if (side == Right && fi == Infix && ai == Right) return (fo == Infix && ao == Right);
    if (side == Noassoc) {
        if (fi == Infix && fo == Infix) return ai == ao;
        return fi == fo;
    }
    return false;
}

struct StackElem {
    Oper *infixop;
    const Expr *exp;
    std::vector<Oper*> prefixes;

    StackElem(Oper* i, const Expr* e, std::vector<Oper*> pref) 
        : infixop(i), exp(e), prefixes(pref) {}
};
std::map<std::string, Oper*> OperatorMap;
Oper *juxtarator = new Oper(" <juxtarator> ", 100, Infix, Left);
Oper *minrator = new Oper(" <minimal precedence operator> ", -1, Infix, Noassoc);
Oper *srator(std::stack<StackElem> const& st) { return (st.empty() ? minrator : st.top().infixop); }

Oper* get_op(std::string s) {
    auto it = OperatorMap.find(s);
    if (it == OperatorMap.end()) return nullptr;
    return it->second;
}

Expr* parse_postfix(const std::stack<StackElem> stack, const Expr* e, const std::vector<Oper*> prefixes, const std::vector<std::string> ipts);

Expr* parse_prefix(const std::stack<StackElem> stack, const std::vector<Oper*> prefixes, const std::vector<std::string> ipts) {
    if (!ipts.empty()) {
        std::string head = ipts[0];
        std::vector<std::string> tail(ipts.begin() + 1, ipts.end());

        Oper* op = get_op(head);
        if (!op) return parse_postfix(stack, new ConstExpr(std::atoi(head.c_str())), prefixes, tail);
        if (op->Fix == Prefix) {
            std::vector<Oper*> newprefix = prefixes;
            newprefix.push_back(op);
            return parse_prefix(stack, prefixes, tail);
        }
        else throw std::string("Lookahead is not a prefix operator");
    }
    else throw std::string("Premature EOF");
}

Expr* parse_postfix(const std::stack<StackElem> stack, const Expr* e, const std::vector<Oper*> prefixes, const std::vector<std::string> ipts)
{
    if (prefixes.empty() && !ipts.empty()) {
        std::string head = ipts[0];
        std::vector<std::string> tail(ipts.begin() + 1, ipts.end());

        Oper* irator = get_op(head);
        if (irator) {
            if (irator->Fix == Postfix) {
                if (noparens(srator(stack), irator, Left)) {
                    if (!stack.empty()) {
                        StackElem el = stack.top();
                        std::stack<StackElem> stack_tail = stack;
                        stack_tail.pop();
                        return parse_postfix(stack_tail, new BinExpr(el.exp, e, el.infixop), el.prefixes, ipts);
                    } 
                    else throw std::string("Impossible");
                }
                else if (noparens(irator, srator(stack), Right)) {
                    return parse_postfix(stack, new UryExpr(e, irator), std::vector<Oper*>(), tail);
                }
                else throw std::string("Non-associative");
            }
            else if (irator->Fix == Infix) {
                if (noparens(srator(stack), irator, Left)) {
                    if (!stack.empty()) {
                        StackElem el = stack.top();
                        std::stack<StackElem> stack_tail = stack;
                        stack_tail.pop();
                        return parse_postfix(stack_tail, new BinExpr(el.exp, e, el.infixop), el.prefixes, ipts);
                    }
                    else throw std::string("Impossible");
                }
                else if (noparens(irator, srator(stack), Right)) {
                    std::stack<StackElem> newstack = stack;
                    newstack.push(StackElem(irator, e, std::vector<Oper*>()));
                    return parse_prefix(newstack, std::vector<Oper*>(), tail);
                }
                else throw std::string("Non-associative");
            }
        }
    }
    else if (!prefixes.empty() && !ipts.empty()) {
        std::string head = ipts[0];
        std::vector<std::string> tail(ipts.begin() + 1, ipts.end());
        Oper* op = prefixes[0];
        std::vector<Oper*> newprefixes(prefixes.begin() + 1, prefixes.end());

        Oper* irator = get_op(head);
        if (irator) {
            if (irator->Fix == Postfix) {
                if (noparens(op, irator, Noassoc)) {
                    return parse_postfix(stack, new UryExpr(e, op), newprefixes, ipts);
                }
                else if (noparens(irator, op, Noassoc)) {
                    return parse_postfix(stack, new UryExpr(e, irator), prefixes, tail);
                }
                else throw std::string("Equal precedence!");
            }
            else if (irator->Fix == Infix) {
                if (noparens(op, irator, Noassoc)) {
                    parse_postfix(stack, new UryExpr(e, op), newprefixes, ipts);
                }
                else if (noparens(irator, op, Noassoc)) {
                    std::stack<StackElem> newstack = stack;
                    newstack.push(StackElem(irator, e, prefixes));
                    return parse_prefix(newstack, std::vector<Oper*>(), tail);
                }
                else throw std::string("Equal precedence!");
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> nnip = ipts;
    nnip.insert(nnip.begin(), juxtarator->Symbol);
    return parse_postfix(stack, e, prefixes, nnip);
}

Expr* parse(std::vector<std::string> input) {
    return parse_prefix(std::stack<StackElem>(), std::vector<Oper*>(), input);
}

int main(void)
{
    OperatorMap.insert(std::make_pair(minrator->Symbol, minrator));
    OperatorMap.insert(std::make_pair(juxtarator->Symbol, juxtarator));
    OperatorMap.insert(std::make_pair("+", new Oper("+", 3, Infix, Left)));
    std::vector<std::string> tokens = { "2", "+", "3" };
    try {
        Expr* e = parse(tokens);
    }
    catch (std::string err) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm hoping that this part is corect with parse prefix but I don't know how about implementing the `parse_postfix` function.

Edit:

Now this tries to be the full test program but it fails for some reason, as for the input "2" "+" "3" (or even just a single number) an exception is triggered (Premature EOF).

Comment: The algorithm is described in some detail in the paper.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, but an example implementation would be nice to look at.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> parse_postfix(stack, (e, []),
>               ipts as RATOR (irator as (_, _, POSTFIX)) :: ipts') = ...
> ```
>
> This means that `ipts` is the head of the list `ipts'` and is a postfix operator?

Not exactly. the `as` match operator actually binds less tight than pattern constructors like `::`; adding proper parentheses, `ipts` becomes the full list with `RATOR ...` as the head and `ipts'` (one element short) as the tail:

```
parse_postfix(stack, (e, []),
              ipts as (RATOR (irator as (_, _, POSTFIX)) :: ipts')) = ...
```

> Why is there another match inside (`irator as...`)?

Here the `as` match operator is used for two distinct purposes:

1. The `ipts as (... :: ipts')` and the `irator as (_, _, POSTFIX)` patterns are used to guarantee that the variables `ipts` and `irator` cover things of a particular sub-structure, so in the function body it is guaranteed that `ipts` is never empty and that `irator` is always a postfix-style *rator* (since otherwise it's not `parse_postfix`'s job to handle it).
2. As a small performance enhancement. Norman could also have written e.g.

   ```
   parse_postfix(stack, (e, []),
                 RATOR (text, prec, POSTFIX) :: ipts') = ...
   ```

   and subsequently refer to `RATOR (text, prec, POSTFIX)` whenever he refers to `irator` and `RATOR (text, prec, POSTFIX :: ipts'` whenever he refers to `ipts`. But this is both longer, harder to read, and requires re-construction of values that are already constructed in memory when referring to `irator` and `ipts` (i.e. less copying).

   Instead, the helper function `noparens`, the value constructor `UNARY`, the exception `ParseError`, etc. are all designed to handle the `irator` 3-tuple directly for that convenience.

> Does it remove it from the list or advances anyway? Or is `ipts` the remainder of the list when the operator `irator` is removed?

Sometimes, and almost. `ipts'` is the remainder of the list when `irator` has been removed while `ipts` is the full list with no elements removed. Depending on whether `ipts` or `ipts'` are referred to in the *if-then-else*s, an element is popped or not.

> I'm hoping that this part is corect with parse prefix but I don't know how about implementing the `parse_postfix` function.

I can't say right now. But one thing is certain: It will be much simpler to translate these functions if you stick with immutable data structures. It won't run as fast, though.

Comment: Very nice answer, clarifies a lot! Would you mind taking a look if I implement the rest?

Comment: I have edited my answer but the program does not produce the expected output so I think I'm still doing something wrong.